# How to copy all attributes from one AttributedString to another without converting to NSAttributedString?

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, attributedstring

I have an AttributedString with a set of attributes I don't know until runtime. Now I want to append / prepend another string. How do I get the appended string to have the same attributes as the original AttributedString? Copying the attributes from the first character is fine, as the entire AttributedString has homogenous attributes.

I see I can create a new AttributedString with the new appended text, then call "setAttributes" on it, but see no way to get the AttributeContainer from the original string? Is there a way to do this that doesn't involve copying each attribute individually?

I see this is possible with NSAttributedString, but is it possible without converting to NSAttributedString?

I would hope I could do something like:

```
let originalText: AttributedString // Some existing string with arbitrary attributes
var newText = AttributedString("text_I_want_to_prepend_to_originalText")
newText.setAttributes(originalText.getAttributes(at: 0))
newText.append(originalText)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The containers are attached to each `AttributedString.Run` (which is a range of characters with the same attributes). You can access them this way:

```
newText.setAttributes(originalText.runs.first!.attributes)
```

Obviously you should think carefully about how this would work if the string is empty, since that would crash. But the basic approach is to access the `runs` property.

There is a subscript on `runs` that accepts `AttributeString.Index`, so a version that more precisely matches your original `getAttributes(at: 0)` would be:

```
newText.setAttributes(originalText.runs[originalText.startIndex].attributes)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [init(_:attributes:) | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/attributedstring/3765845-init)
with default set of attributes:

```swift
let defaultAttributes = AttributeContainer().font(.body).foregroundColor(.green)
    
var newText = AttributedString("text_I_want_to_prepend_to_originalText",
                  attributes: string.runs.first?.attributes ?? defaultAttributes)
```